# Mirror vertex group failed

Tags: armature, weight-painting, mirror, error

When I try to mirror vertex group in weight paint mode, error shows up ''0 vertices mirrored 11226 failed''

I've tried:  - mirror half of the model, so everything is symmetrical,
- center everything on the X, Y than ctrl + a
- attach the armature to different model > mirror vertices worked
- attach the model to different armature > error

There is clearly something wrong with the model but I have no idea what is causing all the problems. I made the model in Maya 2016 than exported it as .obj than did the Uv mapping + textures in blender 2.8.
I don't want to do retopology, so I'm asking for help.

Here's the model in blender: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iykZkZBXoBTzXScjjGUdMEzCR_mOCCdk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by importing the model and armature in a new scene.